Failed to create a market ID
The 3 different sites I have used to try to create market ID each show me a failed transaction or or some other error message. The "Failed to load spl token data" was the error message on openbookdex.org and solauncher.org ....
On v2.raydium.io/create-market/ I was given the "This transaction reverted during simulation. Funds may be lost if submitted." error message when attempting to complete the process of creating an openbook market using raydium.
I have even tried both desktop and mobile versions of some of these sites.
Does the Metadata of the token have something to do with why these attempts are failing on these sites? I'm trying to solve this problem and this is what I have so far.
Is it something else? Please help

Raydium has deployed a new standard AMM program (CP-Swap), which adds support for Token-2022 assets and no longer requires an OpenBook market ID.
Program Address: CPMMoo8L3F4NbTegBCKVNunggL7H1ZpdTHKxQB5qKP1C
Radium Docs
